# How to combine django model with function based view

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django view in which I wish to read a cookie

**urls.py**:

```
path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

**views.py**:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    url = 'home/home_page.html'
    cookies_allowed = request.COOKIES.get('cookies_allowed', '0')
    return render(request, url, context)
```

**models.py**:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    template = "home/home_page.html"    
    banner_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
```

But, of course, the *render* function does not contain any context data and I get a blank page.

How do I get the data defined in the model into context?

Comment: have you tried something like this `context={'my_model_qs':HomePage.objects.all()}`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Thanks. But how do I use that?

Comment: paste instead of `context = {}` in your function. I felt you're a noob to Django. I invite you to take a look at the [Django Official Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) to get more grip.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes. I've done that, but that just gives {'my_model_qs': <PageQuerySet [<HomePage: Home>]>}. How do I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = {'data': HomePage.objects.all()}
    url = 'home/home_page.html'
    cookies_allowed = request.COOKIES.get('cookies_allowed', '0')
    return render(request, url, context)
```

home_page.html

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {{obj.banner_title}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The html is what I needed.

Comment: Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

**views.py:**

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    url = 'home/home_page.html'
    cookies_allowed = request.COOKIES.get('cookies_allowed', '0')
    data = ModelName.objects.all()
    context = {
                'data':data
    }
    return render(request, url, context)
```

models.py:

class ModelName(models.Model):

```
banner_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
```

Look, model is using to define the table field  as a model attribute. So there is no template or anything in here.